# why prompt "No provider for framework:requirejs" when run karma

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner

I have install karma-requirejs and requires,but when running Karma,The console prompt "No provider for "framework:requirejs"";
please help me,thank you!!

Comment: Hard to say without code... Could you edit your question and paste your karma config please? How have you installed requireJS?

Answer (score 1):

I know this issue is a bit older but I hit it while searching for a solution, so maybe this helps other to solve their problem quicker.

Even without code it might be due to missing the `karma-requirejs` plugin reference. (That's the issue I just had.)

Just add it to your `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    ...

    plugins: [
      ...
      'karma-requirejs'
    ],

    ...
  });
};
```

You also might need to install it via `npm install karma-requirejs --save-dev` if not yet done.